# Linux Mint: Switch Wacom pen sides

Tags: linux, linux-mint, thinkpad

I am running Linux Mint 17 x64 on Cinnamon. I have a Lenovo Thinkpad X220 with tablet. My pen has something wrong with it (Windows and Linux) where the eraser and pen are flipped when it registers. When I try to click and and change the settings for the main point, it uses the eraser settings, and vice versa.

Is there a way to change this at the software level? A bit of poking around with xsetwacom and I did not find a way to do this, but I feel like there might be.

mint ~ # xsetwacom --list devices
Wacom ISDv4 E6 Pen stylus           id: 10  type: STYLUS
Wacom ISDv4 E6 Finger touch         id: 11  type: TOUCH
Wacom ISDv4 E6 Pen eraser           id: 16  type: ERASER